# Dispatch event on:click:row--select from Svelte DataTable

Tags: javascript, svelte, dispatch

I am trying to use a dispatch event from https://carbon-components-svelte.onrender.com/components/DataTable namely the: `on:click:row--select { selected: boolean; row: DataTableRow; }` but i cannot get it to work

I found the custom event:

```
["click:row--select"]: CustomEvent<{
      selected: boolean;
      row: DataTableRow;
    }>;
```

But i dont know how to integrate it with my code

```
addEventListener("click:row--select", handleSelect);

function handleSelect(e) {
   e.selected;
   e.Modal;
}
```

Comment: You might want to do [the tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial) if you have not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events in Svelte are added on the component as attributes [starting with `on:`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-component-directives-on-eventname), so somewhere in the markup you should have:

```html
<DataTable ... on:click:row--select={handleSelect}>
```